# Showing google chart dynamically in div using php and ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, google-visualization

I am trying to show multiple results in single php page, one of them is Google pie chart which takes data from mysql db. Without ajax I can show this chart separately successfully but using ajax to show the graph on same page has no luck.

Below code works, but on button click it redirects to ajax_graph_temp.php and shows graph on that page. I want using ajax to show the graph on same page i.e. ajax_form.php.

Problem is ajax_graph.php showing the result in `div` which is present in it only. How can I show it in the dive present in ajax_form_temp.php?

my ajax_form_temp.php:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function viewChart(form, e){
        e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue=false;    
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
        else{// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    }
    xmlhttp.open(form.method, form.action, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
        xmlhttp.send();
}

       //------------------Chart function end
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="ajax_graph_temp.php" method="post"/>
    <h4>CLICK TO VIEW CHART</h4>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" name="view"/>
   </form>

    <br />
    <div id="txtHint">
        <b>Person info will be listed here.</b>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and ajax_graph_temp.php is:

```
<?php
echo "hi";
$mysqli =mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
  $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM new_view');

  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'ind_type', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Index_val', 'type' => 'number')

);
    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($result as $r) {

      $temp = array();

      // The following line will be used to slice the Pie chart

      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['ind_type']); 

      // Values of the each slice

      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Index_val']); 
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
//echo $jsonTable;

  ?>
    <html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);
      var options = {
           title: 'Index analysis',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
      <body>
    <!--this is the div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pasting entire files is kinda frowned upon here.  You'll have better luck finding an answer if you post only relevant code.

Comment: @SomeKittens: I have updated the code removing unrelaaant code!

Comment: Thank goodness misspelling isn't also kinda frowned upon :-)